# logman query providers for a guid

Tags: windows, wpr

I am creating a Diagnostic Capture Plan for the investigation of a performance problem.  We are going to use Windows Performance Recorder to capture FileIO and Network metrics.  However, I'm struggling with one particular detail.

I want to use the WPR profile Network.  I can list the profile details with wpr -profiledetails Network.  The output includes the providers and the keywords.  Most providers have names and so I can display the keyword details with logman query providers -n _provider_name_.  Some providers have no name, e.g.

36b6f488-aad7-48c2-afe3-d4ec2c8b46fa: 0x10000: 0xff

How can I display the meaning of the keywords?

Thanks and regards...Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According the reply of the Mirosoft employee `Paul E Long` to this topic](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/86ac7248-a85e-4d57-838b-8782f112fe23/how-to-read-wpr-etl-file-with-custom-manifest-?forum=messageanalyzer), `36b6f488-aad7-48c2-afe3-d4ec2c8b46fa` is the GUID for the control that WPR and WPRUI use to enable providers.

The keyword 0x10000 is related to perfstatus events from WPR:

```
<keyword mask="0x10000" message="$(string.Keyword.PerfStatus)" name="PerfStatus"/>
```

Here is the complete manifest:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes'?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" manifestVersion="1.0">
 <assemblyIdentity buildType="$(build.buildType)" language="neutral" name="Microsoft-Windows-Core-Fundamentals-EcoPlatforms-WPRControl" processorArchitecture="$(build.processorArchitecture)" publicKeyToken="$(Build.WindowsPublicKeyToken)" version="$(build.version)" versionScope="nonSxS"/>
 <instrumentation>
  <events xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events" xmlns:win="http://manifests.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/windows/events" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <provider guid="{36b6f488-aad7-48c2-afe3-d4ec2c8b46fa}" message="$(string.DiagnosticsPerformanceProviderName)" messageFileName="WindowsPerformanceRecorderControl.dll" name="Microsoft-Windows-Performance-Recorder-Control" resourceFileName="WindowsPerformanceRecorderControl.dll" symbol="WindowsPerformanceRecorderControlProvider">
    <channels>
     <channel chid="EventLog" enabled="true" isolation="Application" message="$(string.OperationalChannelName)" name="Microsoft-Windows-Performance-Recorder-Control/Operational" type="Operational"/>
     <channel chid="DebugLog" name="Microsoft-Windows-Performance-Recorder-Control/Diagnostic" type="Analytic"/>
    </channels>
    <keywords>
     <keyword mask="0x10000" message="$(string.Keyword.PerfStatus)" name="PerfStatus"/>
     <keyword mask="0x20000" message="$(string.Keyword.DebugStatus)" name="DebugStatus"/>
     <keyword mask="0x40000" message="$(string.Keyword.Informational)" name="Informational"/>
    </keywords>
    <tasks>
     <task name="Perf_ExternalCall" value="100"/>
     <task name="Perf_LoadProfileFromFile" value="101"/>
     <task name="Perf_LoadProfileFromString" value="102"/>
     <task name="Perf_AddProfileToCollection" value="103"/>
     <task name="Perf_RemoveProfileFromCollection" value="104"/>
     <task name="Perf_IsEqualProfile" value="105"/>
     <task name="Perf_IsEqualProfileCollection" value="106"/>
     <task name="Perf_IsEqualTraceMergeProperties" value="107"/>
     <task name="Perf_LoadTraceMergePropertiesFromFile" value="108"/>
     <task name="Perf_LoadTraceMergePropertiesFromString" value="109"/>
     <task name="Perf_StartProfiles" value="110"/>
     <task name="Perf_UpdateProfiles" value="111"/>
     <task name="Perf_CancelProfiles" value="112"/>
     <task name="Perf_SaveProfiles" value="113"/>
     <task name="Perf_StopProfiles" value="114"/>
     <task name="Perf_QueryProfiles" value="115"/>
     <task name="Perf_EnableBootTracing" value="116"/>
     <task name="Perf_DisableBootTracing" value="117"/>
     <task name="Perf_QueryBuiltInProfiles" value="118"/>
     <task name="Perf_ControlProgressHandlerBegin" value="119"/>
     <task name="Perf_ControlProgressHandlerUpdate" value="120"/>
     <task name="Perf_ControlProgressHandlerEnd" value="121"/>
     <task name="Perf_StartShutdownProfiles" value="122"/>
     <task name="Perf_UpdateShutdownProfiles" value="123"/>
     <task name="Perf_MergeShutdownProfiles" value="124"/>
     <task name="Perf_CaptureState" value="125"/>
     <task name="Perf_WPRProfileIds" value="126"/>
     <task name="Debug_WPRCControl" value="200"/>
    </tasks>
    <templates>
     <template tid="Perf_LoadProfileFromFile">
      <data inType="win:UnicodeString" name="ProfileName" outType="xs:string"/>
      <data inType="win:UnicodeString" name="FileName" outType="xs:string"/>
     </template>
     <template tid="Perf_LoadTraceMergePropertiesFromFile">
      <data inType="win:UnicodeString" name="TraceMergePropertyName" outType="xs:string"/>
      <data inType="win:UnicodeString" name="FileName" outType="xs:string"/>
     </template>
     <template tid="Perf_SaveProfiles">
      <data inType="win:UnicodeString" name="FileName" outType="xs:string"/>
     </template>
     <template tid="Perf_StopProfiles">
      <data inType="win:UnicodeString" name="FileName" outType="xs:string"/>
     </template>
     <template tid="Perf_CaptureState">
      <data inType="win:UnicodeString" name="Provider" outType="xs:string"/>
      <data inType="win:UnicodeString" name="Error" outType="xs:string"/>
     </template>
     <template tid="Perf_WPRProfileIds">
      <data inType="win:UnicodeString" name="ProfileIds" outType="xs:string"/>
     </template>
     <template tid="Debug_WPRCControl">
      <data inType="win:UInt32" name="DebugType"/>
      <data inType="win:UInt32" name="ObjectType"/>
      <data inType="win:Int32" name="HResult" outType="win:HResult"/>
      <data inType="win:UInt32" name="LineNumber"/>
      <data inType="win:UnicodeString" name="FileName" outType="xs:string"/>
      <data inType="win:UnicodeString" name="FunctionName" outType="xs:string"/>
     </template>
    </templates>
    <events>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Start" symbol="Perf_ExternalCall_Begin" task="Perf_ExternalCall" value="100" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Stop" symbol="Perf_ExternalCall_End" task="Perf_ExternalCall" value="101" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Start" symbol="Perf_LoadProfileFromFile_Begin" task="Perf_LoadProfileFromFile" template="Perf_LoadProfileFromFile" value="102" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Stop" symbol="Perf_LoadProfileFromFile_End" task="Perf_LoadProfileFromFile" value="103" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Start" symbol="Perf_LoadProfileFromString_Begin" task="Perf_LoadProfileFromString" value="104" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Stop" symbol="Perf_LoadProfileFromString_End" task="Perf_LoadProfileFromString" value="105" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Start" symbol="Perf_AddProfileToCollection_Begin" task="Perf_AddProfileToCollection" value="106" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Start" symbol="Perf_IsEqualProfile_Begin" task="Perf_IsEqualProfile" value="107" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Start" symbol="Perf_IsEqualProfile_End" task="Perf_IsEqualProfile" value="108" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Stop" symbol="Perf_AddProfileToCollection_End" task="Perf_AddProfileToCollection" value="109" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Start" symbol="Perf_RemoveProfileFromCollection_Begin" task="Perf_RemoveProfileFromCollection" value="110" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Stop" symbol="Perf_RemoveProfileFromCollection_End" task="Perf_RemoveProfileFromCollection" value="111" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Stop" symbol="Perf_IsEqualProfileCollection_Begin" task="Perf_IsEqualProfileCollection" value="112" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Stop" symbol="Perf_IsEqualProfileCollection_End" task="Perf_IsEqualProfileCollection" value="113" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Start" symbol="Perf_LoadTraceMergePropertiesFromFile_Begin" task="Perf_LoadTraceMergePropertiesFromFile" template="Perf_LoadTraceMergePropertiesFromFile" value="114" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Stop" symbol="Perf_LoadTraceMergePropertiesFromFile_End" task="Perf_LoadTraceMergePropertiesFromFile" value="115" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Start" symbol="Perf_LoadTraceMergePropertiesFromString_Begin" task="Perf_LoadTraceMergePropertiesFromString" value="116" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Stop" symbol="Perf_LoadTraceMergePropertiesFromString_End" task="Perf_LoadTraceMergePropertiesFromString" value="117" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Stop" symbol="Perf_IsEqualTraceMergeProperties_Begin" task="Perf_IsEqualTraceMergeProperties" value="118" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Stop" symbol="Perf_IsEqualTraceMergeProperties_End" task="Perf_IsEqualTraceMergeProperties" value="119" version="0"/>
     <event channel="EventLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" message="$(string.Event.StartProfiles_Begin)" opcode="win:Start" symbol="Perf_StartProfiles_Begin" task="Perf_StartProfiles" value="120" version="0"/>
     <event channel="EventLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" message="$(string.Event.StartProfiles_End)" opcode="win:Stop" symbol="Perf_StartProfiles_End" task="Perf_StartProfiles" value="121" version="0"/>
     <event channel="EventLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" message="$(string.Event.UpdateProfiles_Begin)" opcode="win:Start" symbol="Perf_UpdateProfiles_Begin" task="Perf_UpdateProfiles" value="122" version="0"/>
     <event channel="EventLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" message="$(string.Event.UpdateProfiles_End)" opcode="win:Stop" symbol="Perf_UpdateProfiles_End" task="Perf_UpdateProfiles" value="123" version="0"/>
     <event channel="EventLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" message="$(string.Event.CancelProfiles_Begin)" opcode="win:Start" symbol="Perf_CancelProfiles_Begin" task="Perf_CancelProfiles" value="124" version="0"/>
     <event channel="EventLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" message="$(string.Event.CancelProfiles_End)" opcode="win:Stop" symbol="Perf_CancelProfiles_End" task="Perf_CancelProfiles" value="125" version="0"/>
     <event channel="EventLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" message="$(string.Event.SaveProfiles_Begin)" opcode="win:Start" symbol="Perf_SaveProfiles_Begin" task="Perf_SaveProfiles" template="Perf_SaveProfiles" value="126" version="0"/>
     <event channel="EventLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" message="$(string.Event.SaveProfiles_End)" opcode="win:Stop" symbol="Perf_SaveProfiles_End" task="Perf_SaveProfiles" value="127" version="0"/>
     <event channel="EventLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" message="$(string.Event.StopProfiles_Begin)" opcode="win:Start" symbol="Perf_StopProfiles_Begin" task="Perf_StopProfiles" template="Perf_StopProfiles" value="128" version="0"/>
     <event channel="EventLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" message="$(string.Event.StopProfiles_End)" opcode="win:Stop" symbol="Perf_StopProfiles_End" task="Perf_StopProfiles" value="129" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Start" symbol="Perf_QueryProfiles_Begin" task="Perf_QueryProfiles" value="130" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Stop" symbol="Perf_QueryProfiles_End" task="Perf_QueryProfiles" value="131" version="0"/>
     <event channel="EventLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" message="$(string.Event.EnableBootTracing_Begin)" opcode="win:Start" symbol="Perf_EnableBootTracing_Begin" task="Perf_EnableBootTracing" value="132" version="0"/>
     <event channel="EventLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" message="$(string.Event.EnableBootTracing_End)" opcode="win:Stop" symbol="Perf_EnableBootTracing_End" task="Perf_EnableBootTracing" value="133" version="0"/>
     <event channel="EventLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" message="$(string.Event.DisableBootTracing_Begin)" opcode="win:Start" symbol="Perf_DisableBootTracing_Begin" task="Perf_DisableBootTracing" value="134" version="0"/>
     <event channel="EventLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" message="$(string.Event.DisableBootTracing_End)" opcode="win:Stop" symbol="Perf_DisableBootTracing_End" task="Perf_DisableBootTracing" value="135" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Start" symbol="Perf_QueryBuiltInProfiles_Begin" task="Perf_QueryBuiltInProfiles" value="136" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Stop" symbol="Perf_QueryBuiltInProfiles_End" task="Perf_QueryBuiltInProfiles" value="137" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Start" symbol="Perf_ControlProgressHandlerBegin_Begin" task="Perf_ControlProgressHandlerBegin" value="138" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Stop" symbol="Perf_ControlProgressHandlerBegin_End" task="Perf_ControlProgressHandlerBegin" value="139" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Start" symbol="Perf_ControlProgressHandlerUpdate_Begin" task="Perf_ControlProgressHandlerUpdate" value="140" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Stop" symbol="Perf_ControlProgressHandlerUpdate_End" task="Perf_ControlProgressHandlerUpdate" value="141" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Start" symbol="Perf_ControlProgressHandlerEnd_Begin" task="Perf_ControlProgressHandlerEnd" value="142" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Stop" symbol="Perf_ControlProgressHandlerEnd_End" task="Perf_ControlProgressHandlerEnd" value="143" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Start" symbol="Perf_StartShutdownProfiles_Begin" task="Perf_StartShutdownProfiles" value="144" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Stop" symbol="Perf_StartShutdownProfiles_End" task="Perf_StartShutdownProfiles" value="145" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Start" symbol="Perf_UpdateShutdownProfiles_Begin" task="Perf_UpdateShutdownProfiles" value="146" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Stop" symbol="Perf_UpdateShutdownProfiles_End" task="Perf_UpdateShutdownProfiles" value="147" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Start" symbol="Perf_MergeShutdownProfiles_Begin" task="Perf_MergeShutdownProfiles" template="Perf_SaveProfiles" value="148" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Stop" symbol="Perf_MergeShutdownProfiles_End" task="Perf_MergeShutdownProfiles" value="149" version="0"/>
     <event channel="EventLog" keywords="PerfStatus" level="win:Informational" message="$(string.Event.Perf_captureState_Failed)" opcode="win:Info" symbol="Perf_CaptureState_Failed" task="Perf_CaptureState" template="Perf_CaptureState" value="150" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="Informational" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Info" symbol="Perf_WPRProfileIds" task="Perf_WPRProfileIds" template="Perf_WPRProfileIds" value="151" version="0"/>
     <event channel="DebugLog" keywords="DebugStatus" level="win:Warning" opcode="win:Info" symbol="Debug_WPRCControl" task="Debug_WPRCControl" template="Debug_WPRCControl" value="200" version="0"/>
    </events>
   </provider>
   <provider guid="{b7a19fcd-15ba-41ba-a3d7-dc352d5f79ba}" message="$(string.ContextProviderName)" messageFileName="WindowsPerformanceRecorderControl.dll" name="Microsoft-Windows-Performance-Recorder-Context" resourceFileName="WindowsPerformanceRecorderControl.dll" symbol="WindowsPerformanceRecorderContextProvider">
    <channels>
     <channel chid="AnalyticLog" name="Microsoft-Windows-Performance-Recorder-Context/Analytic" type="Analytic"/>
    </channels>
    <keywords>
     <keyword mask="0x1" message="$(string.Keyword.ScreenCapture)" name="ScreenCapture"/>
     <keyword mask="0x2" message="$(string.Keyword.WindowCapture)" name="WindowCapture"/>
    </keywords>
    <tasks>
     <task name="ScreenCapture" value="101"/>
     <task name="ScreenCaptureMonitorData" value="103"/>
     <task name="ScreenCapturePixelData" value="105"/>
     <task name="WindowCapture" value="107"/>
     <task name="WindowData" value="109"/>
    </tasks>
    <templates>
     <template tid="ScreenCaptureMonitorData">
      <data inType="win:Int32" name="Top"/>
      <data inType="win:Int32" name="Left"/>
      <data inType="win:Int32" name="Bottom"/>
      <data inType="win:Int32" name="Right"/>
      <data inType="win:GUID" name="PixelDataId"/>
      <data inType="win:UnicodeString" name="MonitorName" outType="xs:string"/>
     </template>
     <template tid="ScreenCapturePixelData">
      <data inType="win:GUID" name="PixelDataId"/>
      <data inType="win:UInt32" name="CompressionFormat"/>
      <data inType="win:UInt32" name="TotalUncompressedSize"/>
      <data inType="win:UInt32" name="TotalCompressedSize"/>
      <data inType="win:UInt32" name="CompressedChunkSize"/>
      <data inType="win:UInt32" name="ChunkIndex"/>
      <data inType="win:UInt32" name="ChunkSize"/>
      <data inType="win:AnsiString" name="ContentType"/>
      <data inType="win:Binary" length="ChunkSize" name="ChunkData"/>
     </template>
     <template tid="WindowData">
      <data inType="win:UInt32" name="Handle" outType="win:HexInt32"/>
      <data inType="win:UInt32" name="CreatingProcessId"/>
      <data inType="win:UInt32" name="CreatingThreadId"/>
      <data inType="win:Int32" name="Top"/>
      <data inType="win:Int32" name="Left"/>
      <data inType="win:Int32" name="Bottom"/>
      <data inType="win:Int32" name="Right"/>
      <data inType="win:UInt32" name="Status" outType="win:HexInt32"/>
      <data inType="win:UnicodeString" name="Title"/>
     </template>
     <template tid="Scenario">
      <data inType="win:UnicodeString" name="Scenario" outType="xs:string"/>
      <data inType="win:UnicodeString" name="Type" outType="xs:string"/>
     </template>
    </templates>
    <events>
     <event opcode="win:Info" symbol="InformationCapture_FireEvent" template="Scenario" value="100" version="0"/>
     <event channel="AnalyticLog" keywords="ScreenCapture" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Start" symbol="ScreenCapture_Start" task="ScreenCapture" value="101" version="0"/>
     <event channel="AnalyticLog" keywords="ScreenCapture" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Stop" symbol="ScreenCapture_Stop" task="ScreenCapture" value="102" version="0"/>
     <event channel="AnalyticLog" keywords="ScreenCapture" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Info" symbol="ScreenCapture_MonitorData" task="ScreenCaptureMonitorData" template="ScreenCaptureMonitorData" value="103" version="0"/>
     <event channel="AnalyticLog" keywords="ScreenCapture" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Info" symbol="ScreenCapture_PixelData" task="ScreenCapturePixelData" template="ScreenCapturePixelData" value="105" version="0"/>
     <event channel="AnalyticLog" keywords="WindowCapture" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Start" symbol="WindowCapture_Start" task="WindowCapture" value="107" version="0"/>
     <event channel="AnalyticLog" keywords="WindowCapture" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Stop" symbol="WindowCapture_Stop" task="WindowCapture" value="108" version="0"/>
     <event channel="AnalyticLog" keywords="WindowCapture" level="win:Informational" opcode="win:Info" symbol="WindowData" task="WindowData" template="WindowData" value="109" version="0"/>
    </events>
   </provider>
  </events>
 </instrumentation>
 <localization>
  <resources culture="en-US">
   <stringTable>
    <string id="DiagnosticsPerformanceProviderName" value="Microsoft-Windows-Performance-Recorder-Control"/>
    <string id="ContextProviderName" value="Microsoft-Windows-Performance-Recorder-Context"/>
    <string id="Keyword.PerfStatus" value="Perf Status"/>
    <string id="Keyword.DebugStatus" value="Debug Status"/>
    <string id="Keyword.Informational" value="Informational"/>
    <string id="OperationalChannelName" value="Operational"/>
    <string id="Keyword.ScreenCapture" value="ScreenCapture"/>
    <string id="Keyword.WindowCapture" value="WindowCapture"/>
    <string id="Event.StartProfiles_Begin" value="A recording profile set is being started..."/>
    <string id="Event.StartProfiles_End" value="A recording profile set has been started."/>
    <string id="Event.UpdateProfiles_Begin" value="A recording profile set is being updated..."/>
    <string id="Event.UpdateProfiles_End" value="A recording profile set has been updated."/>
    <string id="Event.CancelProfiles_Begin" value="A recording profile set is being cancelled..."/>
    <string id="Event.CancelProfiles_End" value="A recording profile set has been cancelled."/>
    <string id="Event.SaveProfiles_Begin" value="A recording profile set is being saved as %1..."/>
    <string id="Event.SaveProfiles_End" value="A recording profile set has been saved."/>
    <string id="Event.StopProfiles_Begin" value="A recording profile set is being stopped as %1..."/>
    <string id="Event.StopProfiles_End" value="A recording profile set has been stopped."/>
    <string id="Event.EnableBootTracing_Begin" value="An on/off recording operation is getting configured..."/>
    <string id="Event.EnableBootTracing_End" value="An on/off recording operation has been configured."/>
    <string id="Event.DisableBootTracing_Begin" value="An on/off recording operation is getting disabled..."/>
    <string id="Event.DisableBootTracing_End" value="An on/off recording operation has been disabled."/>
    <string id="Event.Perf_captureState_Failed" value="CaptureState on a Provider failed.%n%nProvider%t:%t%1%nError%t:%t%2%n"/>
   </stringTable>
  </resources>
 </localization>
</assembly>
```